# Gnome broken after i3 installation

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, i3-wm

I just wanted to give gnome a try again after using i3 for quite a while. When I logged in using a gnome session, there where major graphical glitches ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neoVG.jpg)), lots of error reports (apparently spotify and emacs crashing mmultiple times - both of which work just fine on i3) and everything was super slow at least for the first minute or two after logging in.

The error messages seem to have disappeared after a couple of restarts. The graphical glitches are partially and only temporarily gone after changing the background image and it only seems to be super slow when a screen in connected to my laptop.

I'm kind of lost here and don't really know where to start looking.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 but I remember having similar issues when I accidentally logged into a gnome session when I was on 19.04.

Comment: Your picture reminds me of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1870725 ; no idea if it'll help but maybe worth checking out.

Comment: That did help. Thank you! Turned out to be the intel graphics driver. I uninstalled it and it seems to work now.